# Custom resource method's URL not respected

Tags: angular-resource

I'm trying to make a list of persons. My HTTP server is able to give a JSON representation of a person on URLs like `/person/[id].json`, and a list of all persons at `/person.infinity.json`.

So I have the controller, where I have defined the `Person` resource:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngResource"])

.controller('PersonController', function PersonController($scope, $http, $resource) {
    var Person = $resource("/person/:personId.json",
      { personId: '@id' },
      { list: {method: "GET", url: "/person.infinity.json", isArray: true}}
    );
    $scope.persons = Person.list();

});
```

However, when `Person.list()` is called, my custom URL for the `list` method (`/person.infinity.json`) is not used. Chrome´s network inspector reveals that a request is fired to `/person/.json`, that is, the default resource URL with no parameter set.

Obviously, I would like `Person.list()` to result in a request to `/person.infinity.json`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using angular-resource 1.0.7, in which URL override was not implemented. It was implemented in this pull request: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/1890

Switching to version 1.1.5 solved the problem.